# How to get the template after rendering (Django)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates, django-middleware

I want to have the site template that is sent to the user after rendering in **middleware**.

Comment: This is a bit vague, what do you want exactly the name of the template used for the response? The _rendered content_ of the template? What is the use case supposed to be here? Caching (There is already a middleware for that)?

Comment: I need the rendered code itself. The one from which all parentheses are removed and the information is placed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to download the rendered template with IDM or something :)